# Restoring using SyncBack without profiles

Tags: windows-vista, restore, zip, rar, syncback

I backed up my internal hard drive (C:) using SyncBack onto an external (USB) hard drive with maximum compression. I then performed a clean install of Windows Vista onto the computer.

I forgot to copy the SyncBack logs before the clean install.  And now when ever I try to restore a directory, the RAR/ZIP files are copied to the system hard drive instead of extracting their contents to the hard drive.  Also, SyncBack is not traversing the folders during the Restore process.

How can I tell SyncBack to expand the compressed files?

I am running the freeware version of SyncBack.  I have to create new log files (unless SyncBack put them somewhere on the external drive).

My alternative is to write a program that traverses the folders on the external drive and extracts files from the RAR/ZIP files.

I am using Windows Vista, Service Pack 2, and the data size prior to backup was about 200 GB.  (The backup process took over 72 hours due to "hiccups").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a Java program to traverse the folders and unzip the archives.  The folder tree would be created on the target as necessary.

Unfortunately, *SyncBack* did not backup everything.  A lot of my wife's data is in zero length zip files.  Also, SyncBack does not treat shortcuts correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I used SyncBack some time ago, pretty neat tool for backup/archive ... I would say that try to create a similar profile on another box and just stick in the place where you want to restore. Have a try.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is my home PC and I have no other box like it.